# How to recursively diff without transversing filesystems?

Tags: directory, diff, rsync

I'd like to create a patchset for two directory trees both of which contain (bind-)mounts which should be ignored. Is there any `diff -r` option similar to `rsync`'s `-x, --one-file-system`? Or is another tool more appropriate for this? I considered using `rsync --compare-dest`, but the problem is a "diff"-directory obtained this way contains no information on file deletions.

Background: I want to store the modifications made to a `chroot`ed-into Gentoo stage3 archive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, I currently waste a lot of time by running `rsync` twice:

```bash
ORIG=/path/to/original
MOD=/path/to/modded
# find the modified/added files:
mkdir modded && rsync -axP --prune-empty-dirs --compare-dest=$ORIG $MOD/ modded
# the other way around, includes both deleted and modded files
mkdir deleted && rsync -axP --prune-empty-dirs --compare-dest=$MOD $ORIG/ deleted
# find the modded files and remove them
for i in $(find deleted); do [ -e modded${i#deleted} ] && rm $i; done
# delete the empty directories
find modded delete -type d -empty -delete
# create a list of the deleted files
cd deleted && find -type f > ../deleted.list && cd ..
# tar the modifications
cd modded && tar czf ../modded.tgz && cd ..
rm -rf deleted modded
```

Now `modded.tgz` contains the files that were modified/added, while `deleted.list` contains the names of deleted files, so to apply them run

```bash
tar xf modded.tgz
while read -r line; do rm $line; done < deleted.list
```

This can probably also be used to create a patchfile instead...

Comment: one thing to note: this tripped me up. both ORIG and MOD need to be absolute paths. If they're not rsync throws an error that it can't find it, but since the -P flag is used to show progress, this gets quickly hidden away in the output. The end result is that the entire directory tree is copied, (because it can't find the original), which is definitely not the desired outcome, and in my case since I was diffing filesystems, took ages to complete.